# find element according to parents of elements being siblings

Tags: html, xpath

I have a document like this:

```
...
<ul>
  <div>
  <span>TitleText</span>
  </div>
  <li>
  <span>Choice</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <div>
  <span>AnotherTitle</span>
  </div>
  <li>
  <span>Choice</span>
  </li>
</ul>
...
```

So titles have different text and the two choices have the same name.
I need to be able to select the choice element according to title text.

I tried `"//ul[* = 'AnotherTitle']/following::ul/li/span[* = 'Choice']"` as xpath, but I can't get to the element like this.

What is the correct xpath to get to Choice according to Title? (I can't use counts, the number and position of ul changes with user's role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with something like

```
//ul[div/span='AnotherTitle']/li/span[.='Choice']
```

seems simpler to me, given of course that you always place your title in the div element.

Comment: I am enlightened. What is the div/span part called in xpath lingo? I mean the left side of = when writing element matchers

Comment: I am really not sure :P but you can use anything like that, nest predicates, etc.

Comment: this is pretty awesome, there was a random number next to the title so I ended up writing `//ul/li[div/span[contains(text(),'title')]]/ul/li[div/span[contains(text(),'nest1')]]/ul/li/div/span[contains(text(),'nest2')]` and it selects the span